# How to prevent ruby File from resolving dead symlink

Tags: ruby, file, io

I have a generic file sort method that is crashing because of a dead link in one directory. It seems ruby is trying to resolve the symlink. This happens when I am sorting on a method such as `:mtime` or `:size`.

I want ruby `File` to take the data from the link file (in the current dir) itself without resolving it. When I run a unix `stat` on the said file that *does* give me mtime, atime, ctime etc. I would like to use that.

e.g. `File.mtime("mail")` and `File.stat("mail").mtime` both give me an `ENOENT`.

Please note that when I run `stat mail` in irb (stat in backticks), I do get information for the file.

My original code was:

```
files = files.sort_by { |f| File.send(func, f) }
```

where `func` is a method symbol passed to this method such as `:mtime` or `:atime` or `:size` etc.

My current attempt checks for file existence but then doesn't know what to do to get the values from the file in question.

```
files = files.sort_by do |f| 
    if File.exist? f
       File.send(func, f) }
    else
      # dead link what to do here? I don't want ruby to resolve f
    end
end
```

edit: just to clarify. I do *not* wish to hide dead links. I have to show the entry with the information of the file itself just as Finder or any other file manager would do.

edit: see answer below. `lstat` will give info of dead links.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
files = files.map do |f|
          f = nil unless File.exist?(f)
          f
        end.compact.sort_by { |f| File.send(func, f) }
```

Comment: This will throw an error since a nil cannot be compared to a date or integer.

Comment: You are changing the problem by removing dead links. I could have done that much before getting to this point. If you go to Finder (on OSX for example), you will see a dead link. You will see its date. You can sort that view on modified date. Finder or any other app will not crash because of a dead link.

I cannot just stop displaying dead links. The info is there. But ruby is crashing out since it is resolving the dead link. I want to get the info of the dead link itself. If I do a unix `stat` it gives the info, but I can't be sure which one is present in the path: the GNU or BSD.

Answer (score 0):

`lstat` is what is needed in the case of a dead link.

```
 File.lstat("deadlink").mtime
```

will return the mtime of the referent. One would first check `File.symlink?("deadlink")` and if true one may use `lstat` to get the details.